# Serial.write printing blank values

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I've got an Adafruit Bluefruit NRF52 hooked up to the Adafruit BNO055 9-axis orientation sensor, but when I use Serial.write to send the data, serial monitor displays blank values only. The scroll bar drops so something I definitely appearing, it just seems to be empty.

Serial.print works fine, but I cannot use this for my application, as it uses too much memory.

I'm gathering 3 axis of absolute orientation plus 3 axis of acceleration (6 floats in total) plus a three digit number representing the calibration of each sensor.

Each line should look something like

```
303 68.69   4.19    -2.19   -0.12   0.14    -0.40
```

My code:

```
void displayCalStatus(void)
{

  uint8_t system, gyro, accel, mag;
  system = gyro = accel = mag = 0;
  bno.getCalibration(&system, &gyro, &accel, &mag);

  /* Display the individual values */
  Serial.write(gyro);
  Serial.write(accel);
  Serial.write(mag);
  Serial.write("\t");
}

void loop()
{
  imu::Vector<3> accel = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_LINEARACCEL);

  /* Get a new sensor event */
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  displayCalStatus();

  /* Display the floating point data */
  Serial.write(event.orientation.x);
  Serial.write("\t");
  Serial.write(event.orientation.y);
  Serial.write("\t");
  Serial.write(event.orientation.z);
  Serial.write("\t");

    /* Display the floating point data for Linear Acceleration */
  Serial.write(accel.x());
  Serial.write("\t");
  Serial.write(accel.y());
  Serial.write("\t");
  Serial.write(accel.z());
  Serial.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: `write` transfers a byte, you want `print` text. replace all `write` with `print`

Comment: As mentioned, I cannot use print because it uses too much memory. I'm using Serial for debug but am sending over bleuart in prototype. I'm recording high speed, high fidelity movement and so I need the ble connection interval down to 20ms minimum, which means getting the transfer size down. Do you know if there are workable alternatives to print?

Comment: This is not good coding: `system = gyro = accel = mag = 0;` Instead, explicitly set each one to zero.

Comment: but you want see the number as text or not? if you write(5) you send a  nonprintable byte. if you print(5) it will print "5". imu::Vector takes much more space then C array

Comment: system = gyro = accel = mag = 0; is from the example provided by Adafruit, not my own. Either way that doesn't solve the problem of printing blank values.

Comment: I don't need text, just the float, but whole number would do

Comment: you print tabs and new line. that is text. if you want to see a number in Serial Monitor you must print it as text with `print`

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Since I will be sending over bleuart ultimately, do you know if there is an alternative for me to send the values alone, without tabs and new line text?

Comment: The float values you want to send are 4-bytes long. Serial.write sends 1 byte. To send the raw value, you must send each byte individually, usually by bit-shifting. You would probably do well to send some kind of "end of packet" value to indicate to the receiver that you have now sent all values (in case one gets lost or skipped, the receiver can reset to expect the first value, etc.)

Comment: even then you need delimiters, but then you don't know what is a value and what a delimiter so you need a delimiter byte and escaping of the delimiter byte by repeating it twice in data

Comment: If all values are 4 byte and the number of values sent each round is the same, there is no *need* for delimiters, though it could improve robustness.

Comment: I see. I am unsure how to do this. Are you able to provide an example which I may be able to use?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

You wish to send/display on the *Serial Monitor* the `int` and `float` values generated by your sensor, but `Serial.print()` uses too much memory.

**Solution 1:**

Optimize your sketch to use less memory.

---

**Problem 2:**

`Serial.write()` doesn't cause the values to show up on Serial Monitor, but *something* is getting sent, because I see scrolling activity.

**Solution 2:**

`Serial.write()` sends raw bytes, whereas `Serial.print()` converts a variable to a string (or series of ASCII bytes) and sends that string. For example, `Serial.write(65)` sends `A` to the Serial Monitor because the ASCII value of `A` is `65`; `Serial.print(65)` sends `65` to the Serial Monitor because it converts the numeric value `65` into a string containing the character `6` and the character `5`, and sends that string to Serial Monitor.

The Serial Monitor expects only ASCII data. You are using Serial Monitor for development/debugging, but your final application does not require ASCII, only to transmit the numbers.

`Serial.write()` comes in a few forms. One is `Serial.write(val)` which sends a single byte (named `val`, of type `byte` or compatible). Another is `Serial.write(buf, len)` which sends a series of `len` bytes, starting at the address of memory pointed by by `buf`. (This is often when `buf` is an array of bytes, so `buf` points to the first element of the array.)

If you wanted to send the 4 bytes of a `float` using `Serial.write()`, you could call:

```
Serial.write(&(event.orientation.x), sizeof(event.orientation.x);
```

As an alternative, you can use *bit shifting* to send one byte at a time of the 4-byte float:

```
Serial.write((byte)((event.orientation.x & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
Serial.write((byte)((event.orientation.x & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
Serial.write((byte)((event.orientation.x & 0x0000FF00) >>  8);
Serial.write((byte)((event.orientation.x & 0x000000FF)      );
```

On the receiving end, you need to reconstruct your float by doing the reverse.

But you have multiple 4-byte values to send, in rapid repeating loop, so what happens if your receiver and transmitter get out of sync? Then you might want to put in a "flag" value to indicate the start of a sequence of data and a different flag for the stop of a sequence of data. What happens if your start or stop "flag" value actually shows up as one of the bytes you send as part of a real data byte? Then you need to find some way to modify the "real" data so that it's not to be construed as a flag.

This looks to be getting complicated now? Fortunately, these problems have existed and been solved for decades. Unfortunately, there is no consensus on the best or right way.

I did a quick search and found this arduino library that facilitates packet-based serial communication:

https://github.com/bakercp/PacketSerial

Perhaps that can help you take a bundle of numbers and send them reliably to some other system. I don't know that library in particular, and there are probably others that do something similar. This one claims to be compatible with the PySerial, COBS, and SLIP modules for dealing with packetized serial data communications.